# How to render LaTeX equations on this site?

Tags: support, mathjax

What are the, LaTeX 'tags' used on this site? Sorry, my terminology may be off.

E.g. on TeXworks on my PC its `\(` to open and `\)` to close.
its `\begin{equation}` to open and `\end{equation}` to have an equation on a new line.

On physics forums its `##` to open close, enter as usual for new line.

Tried a few things on here but can't get it.
Tried to search for some instructions too but couldn't find.

Comment: Are you asking how to represent code in your questions here?  For inline math, enclose in backticks (aka grave accent) `x=0`, and for code blocks, indent 4 spaces or highlight and click on the `{}` icon.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If this is a question about the site itself, it should be asked on meta.

Comment: If you were asking about how to enter maths with LaTeX syntax on _other SE sites_ such as [physics.se] or [math.se], you can refer to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020) for a guide to the supported syntax.